# Bug in Python-Ardunio communication with Threads

Tags: python, multithreading, arduino

I've been around this bug all day. I've searched everywhere, tried debugging, but I'm unable to find a solution!

I'm trying to make a python program communicate with an Arduino through threads. This thread sends a "read" command to the Arduino, then waits for an "ok" signal from the Arduino before sending it the "port" that it wants to read from. The Arduino, on the other hand, receives that "read" command and then waits for the analog pin number from Python. After getting the pin number it should retrieve its reading data from the given pin. I've commented the code so it would be nicer to analyse.

As it is, the code works well for one single time: right after the code is re-compiled into the Arduino. **If I run the program again it gets stuck within the "ok" loop**... I tried to use a timmer and force the Arduino to say "ok" but it's not working. Tried clearing the input buffer but with no difference. I'm just desperate at this point on why this is happening and how to solve it.

Note: I'm using Arduino Leonardo

Python code:

```
class AnalogReader(threading.Thread):
def __init__(self, arduino_port, arduino_baudrate, analog_pin, read_rate):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    self.arduino_port = arduino_port
    self.arduino_baudrate = arduino_baudrate
    self.analog_pin = analog_pin
    self.read_rate = read_rate  # add read rate variable
    self.delay = 1/self.read_rate
    self._stop_event = threading.Event()

def stop(self):
    self._stop_event.set()

def run(self):
    # Connect to Arduino
    ser = serial.Serial(self.arduino_port, self.arduino_baudrate)
    ser.reset_input_buffer()

    time.sleep(2)  # wait for the Arduino to initialize
    print("before first read")
    # Send command to start sending analog data
    ser.write(bytes("read", 'utf-8'))

    # Wait for "ok" response
    start_time = time.time()
    while True:
        response = ser.readline().decode().strip()
        print("t " + response)
        if response == "ok":
            break
        elif time.time() - start_time > 3:  # timeout after 5 seconds
            ser.reset_input_buffer()
            ser.write(bytes("read", 'utf-8'))  # send the signal again to try again
            start_time = time.time()  # reset the start time

    # Send command to start sending analog data
    ser.write(bytes(str(self.analog_pin), 'utf-8'))

    # Read and print analog data until interrupted
    while not self._stop_event.is_set():
        try:
            line = ser.readline().decode().strip()
            value = float(line)
            print(value)  # print the received value
        except ValueError:
            pass
        time.sleep(self.delay)  # add sleep for read rate

    # Send command to stop sending analog data
    ser.write(bytes('STOP', 'utf-8'))

    # Close serial connection
    ser.close()
```

Arduino code:

```
    int analogPin;
bool stopReading = false;
float voltage;

void setup() {
  // Start serial communication
  Serial.begin(9600);
  randomSeed(analogRead(0));
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    String command = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');
    if (command == "read") {
      //delay(2);
      Serial.println("ok");
      delay(2);
      analogPin = Serial.parseInt();
      int analogValue;
      while (!stopReading) {
        analogValue = analogRead(analogPin);
        voltage = analogValue * (5.0 / 1023.0) ;
        Serial.println(voltage, 8);
        if (Serial.available() > 0) {
          String command = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');
          if (command == "STOP\n") {
            stopReading = true;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You nether set stopReading because Serial.readStringUntil('\n') return string without delimiter (\n) : try

```
if (command == "STOP") {
            stopReading = true;
          }
```

try it and comme back here if other mistakes.